# Running struts 2 web application using spring boot

Tags: struts2, spring-boot

I see we can integrate struts 2 with spring 4.
I am new to spring boot and I searched a lot to check if we can use struts 2 with spring boot but I did not find any clear answers.
Is it possible to integrate struts 2 and spring boot?

Comment: Elaborate, it's unclear what are you asking

Answer (score 2):

Refer to this [link](https://github.com/linux-china/struts2-spring-boot-integration). It is a simple hello world example with all struts2+boot flavor.